# Passing factory functions to Dash components

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, plotly-dash

In React, it is common for a component to be passed a factory function that tells the component how to render its children (e.g. the [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern). This tends to happen when the component needs to render multiple children that follow a certain template.

In Plotly Dash (which is  wrapper around React), it seems that we can pass components to other components, via composition, e.g.

```py
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),
])
```

However, it seems we can't pass factory functions to components, since it's explicitly forbidden [in the guide](https://dash.plot.ly/plugins):

> JavaScript functions are not valid input arguments

Given this, how can we imitate this factory function pattern in a Dash custom component? I'm trying to create a Dash wrapper for [react-awesome-query-builder](https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder/#use), which wants me to invoke it like this, where `get_children` is a factory function that returns a component.

```js
<Query 
   {...config} 
   get_children={this.getChildren}
   onChange={this.onChange}
></Query>
```

My current idea is that we can pass in a template component to the Query component in Dash, which it can then clone with `React.cloneElement()`, and modify its props, letting me use it like this:

```py
app.layout = Query(child_template=html.Div("Template"))
```

Will this work? If not, is there any way to make these higher order components in Dash?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking. If so, then Dash doesn't quite work that way. Any communication between components happens through the callback functions, listening to either `Input` or `State`. You could have a component return other components in its callback function, and even change them by providing different props when it defines them, but they would not be able to work in other callback functions unless some version (even a skeleton) of them including an ID already existed in the `layout`.

Comment: What I'm making is an input component (a query builder) that needs to generate sub-components (query expressions). I'm not interested in listening to events on the sub-components, just the parent input component. The idea is the user can change the sub-components, causing an update in the parent state, which I then listen to.

Comment: If the user changes the sub-components, and that is supposed to change the parent in any way, then you need a callback that will listen to those sub-components and output to the parent. Dash is built on React, but functions in some distinctly different ways. Do you have any more concrete examples as far as Dash code that we can reference?

Comment: You're right that the parent has to listen to the child, but I believe this can be done in React JavaScript, not in Python

Comment: I agree. I'm not aware of a way to make pure React components work with Dash components.